# How do I resize an array of squished PyQt5 widgets?

Tags: pyqt5

I have a QWidget with a QGridLayout populated by an array of QLineEdit widgets. Sometimes, upon building this QWidget, the QLineEdit widgets get squished as shown in the attached figure. Is there a way I can get the widget to expand to the correct size, so that the QLineEdits are tightly packed but not squished?

[image: array of squished QLineEdit widgets to be expanded]

A minimum working example

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QScrollArea, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QWidget, QMainWindow, QApplication,
    QVBoxLayout, QGridLayout)

class FaultyWidget(QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FaultyWidget, self).__init__()

        self.push_button = QPushButton("Push")
        self.push_button.clicked.connect(self._loadTextFields)

        self.test_widget = QWidget()
        self.test_widget.setLayout(QGridLayout())
        for i in range(3):
            self.test_widget.layout().addWidget(QLineEdit(), i, 0)

        self.main_widget = QWidget()
        self.main_widget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.main_widget.layout().addWidget(self.push_button)
        self.main_widget.layout().addWidget(self.test_widget)

        self.setWidget(self.main_widget)

    def _loadTextFields(self):
        self.test_widget.setParent(None)

        self.test_widget = QWidget()
        self.test_widget.setLayout(QGridLayout())
        for i in range(6):
            self.test_widget.layout().addWidget(QLineEdit(), i, 0)
        self.main_widget.layout().insertWidget(1, self.test_widget)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

        self.main_widget = FaultyWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sometimes, upon building this QWidget"? Please try to be more clear, and consider providing a valid [mre].

Comment: make your window bigger, reduce the layouts contents margins... create a [mre] like musicmante said...

Comment: I have added a minimum working example

Comment: [`self.setWidgetResizable(True)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#widgetResizable-prop).